# sed to insert data in file after a pattern

Tags: bash, shell

I have an xml file and trying to append a shell variable contents into the file using sed. The below command works fine but when I use it in a script, it gives me below error. Any suggestions please

sed: -e expression #1, char 66: unknown command: `<'

```
REQUEST="<abc>abc</abc>\n<xyz>xyz</xyz>"
sed -i "/<NAME>/ i $REQUEST" file.xml

file.xml:
<abc>abc</abc>
<xyz>xyz</xyz>
<NAME>
```

Comment: Works for me. You may have a windows line ending in your script.

Comment: Thats strange, I took out that single line to a new script and it worked too. But my original script still throws the same error, I tried sed -i /<NAME>/ i `echo $REQUEST`" file.xml and that helped for now. Thanks

Comment: You might want to `cat -v scriptname` to see if any stray characters show up.

Comment: BTW, note that the script you have written is susceptible to [shell injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) attacks if the input `REQUEST` is not a fixed string.